# Camera Pose Estimation synthetic data

Tags: simulator, camera-calibration

I'm working on camera calibration and pose estimation.Do you know any software for producing synthetic data? I want to put my camera and my calibration object in the scene and move the calibration object. I want the simulator to give me the positions of calibration object in world's coordinate system and camera's coordinate system and some info like this...
Do you know such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/): you specify the positions of camera and objects in the scene by means of 3D coordinates; then with the *render* command you get the image for the camera.